# TSQL: SUM not working like i thought it would

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.Name,
    ISNULL(CAST(sum((b.qty * b.unit_rate)* b.Eng_RPQ )/100 AS DECIMAL(8,1)),0) AS [EngHours],
    SUM(BR.BlendedRate)
FROM 
    Activity_Details b
INNER JOIN 
    Activity c on b.activity_id = c.id
INNER JOIN 
    Project p on p.id = c.project_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    Discipline a on c.discipline_id = a.id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         a.Name, c.id, 
         CAST(f.POH * (d.HourlyRate * (1-(r.Discount/100))/100) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS BlendedRate 
     FROM 
         Activity_Details b
     INNER JOIN 
         Activity c on b.activity_id = c.id
     INNER JOIN 
         Team f on f.activity_id = c.id
     INNER JOIN 
         SOF_Details d on d.id = f.sof_detail_id
     INNER JOIN 
         Project p on p.id = c.project_id
     INNER JOIN 
         Rate r on r.projectid = p.id
     INNER JOIN 
         Teammate_Type tt on tt.id = f.team_type_id
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
         Discipline a on c.discipline_id = a.id
     GROUP BY 
         a.Name, c.id, f.POH, d.HourlyRate, r.Discount) AS BR ON BR.id = c.id
GROUP BY 
    a.Name
ORDER BY 
    a.Name
```

Which yields:

```
Name            EngHours   BlendedRate
Architechtural  80.8       38.48
Architechtural  80.8       55.33
Architechtural  80.8       55.40
```

I want to SUM this BlendedRate and ROUND it but if i try SUM(BR.BlendedRate) to the SELECT and remove the BR.BlendedRate in the GROUP BY

I get:

```
Name            EngHours    BlendedRate
Architechtural  242.3       895.26
```

I was expecting BlendedRate to equal 149.21

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not add a further outer  `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: In your inner query why are you grouping by `a.Name, c.id, f.POH, d.HourlyRate, r.Discount`, you are not aggregating anything..

Comment: Can you supplied sample records and expected output?  SO has a [great guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on providing good examples.

Comment: vmachan...took that out.  Doesn't solve my issue but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Peter Smith... not sure what you mean.

Comment: The only thing that would make sense is that you have rows with duplicated BlendedRate values that have a NULL value for either b.qty or b.unit_rate or b.Eng_RPQ. This would make it so the EngHours would not be affected by the rows since it would add nothing to the sum, but when switching from a Group By to a sum would allows those duplicated BlendedRates to be expressed individually in the overall SUM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

unable to comment due to reputation. It is a crude solution, but your code is returning duplicated (seemingly 6) records. The code should be fixed elsewhere, but without sample data it is difficult. In the mean time a crude solution would be to add a distinct clause to the sum function

```
SUM( DISTINCT BR.BlendedRate)
```